# How to fix the counting of strings to include the duplicate entries

Tags: python, parsing

I'm having problems figuring out how to get the total count of email addresses there are. The code I have written only comes up with the non-duplicate addresses, where the assignment is asking for the total number including the duplicates.

I've tried the for loop, and just setting count to the len() function and got the same result. I reread the materials and I am completely stumped as to how to include the duplicate entries.

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
if len(fname) == 0:
    fname = "mbox-short.txt"
fh = open(fname)
for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if not line.startswith('From '):
        continue
    words = line.split()
    print(words[1])
count = len(words[1])
print("There were", count, "lines in the file with From as the first word")
```

Expected result: There were 27 lines in the file with From as the first word

Actual Result: There were 14 lines in the file with From as the first word

Comment: After the `for lin` loop, `words` just contains the words from the last line that starts with `From`. You didn't append all the words to a list anywhere.

Comment: `len(words[1])` is the number of characters in `words[1]`, it has nothing to do with counting words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increment a counter variable in the loop that's reading from the file.

```
count = 0
for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line.startswith('From '):
        words = line.split()
        print(words[1])
        count += 1
print("There were", count, "lines in the file with From as the first word")
```

Comment: I needed the words variable to print out the email addresses that are required as well. I may be missing something here.

Comment: I've rewritten the answer

Comment: Thank you Barmar, I can see what you have done clearly and I will learn from this.